Tensorflow keras generator yielded an element that did not match the expected structure - what structure does it expect?
I am trying to make an image classification network with tensorflow keras. I have a directory with subdirectories label_0 and label_1
def load_data(image_dir, img_size=(128, 128), batch_size=32):
    """
    Load the dataset using ImageDataGenerator from the directories.
    """
    # Create an ImageDataGenerator for rescaling the images and data augmentation
    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, validation_split=0.2)

    # Load training data from directories
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        image_dir,
        target_size=img_size,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary'
    )

    # Load validation data from directories
    validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        image_dir,
        target_size=img_size,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        class_mode='binary'
    )

    return train_generator, validation_generator

and I create a model with
def build_cnn(input_shape=(128, 128, 3)):
    """
    Build a simple CNN model.
    """
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

Now, training seems to work fine:
train_generator, validation_generator = CNN.load_data(image_dir)
        # Build the model
        model = CNN.build_cnn()
        model.summary()
        # Train the model
        history = model.fit(
        train_generator,
        epochs=10,
        validation_data=validation_generator
        )

but when I try to load untrained data in another subdirectory to_test:
def load_unlabeled_data(to_test_dir, img_size=(128, 128)):
    """
    Load the unlabeled images for prediction.
    """
    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    test_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
        to_test_dir,
        target_size=img_size,
        batch_size=1,
        class_mode=None,  # No labels for test data
        shuffle=False
    )
    
    return test_generator

and calling it
test_generator = CNN.load_unlabeled_data(to_test_dir)

predictions = model.predict(test_generator)

I get the error
TypeError: `generator` yielded an element that did not match the expected structure. The expected structure was (tf.float32,), but the yielded element was [[[[1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    ...   [1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]]

  [[1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    ...    [1. 1. 1.]    [1.
1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]]

  [[1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    ...    [1. 1. 1.]    [1.
1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]]

  ...

  [[1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    ...    [1. 1. 1.]    [1.
1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]]

  [[1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    ...    [1. 1. 1.]    [1.
1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]]

  [[1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]    ...    [1. 1. 1.]    [1.
1. 1.]    [1. 1. 1.]]]].

I dont even know where to start and I havent found any similar error, or at least nothing what seems similar to my case. What can I do?

does to_test_dir is the to_test subdirectory or is it the directory that contains the to_test subdirectory? I'm asking because ImageDataGenerator expects that the non-label images will also be included in a subdirectory (e.g. /to_test_dir/to_test/)

I replicated your code on a dataset, and I removed the CNN class since it
doesn't exist in your code. These changes made the code work. Please refer to
this gist and let me know if you're still facing any issues.
